# How do I determine the polarizability of a material?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, polarization, dielectric, dipole

Is there a simple and elegant way to determine the polarizability of a material? If so, how? Experimentally, one can easily measure the electric and polarization fields, but measuring polarizability is not that easy.  Additionally, if possible, can anyone explain the theory behind one's measurement scheme, noting any differences when dealing with longitudinal / transverse polarizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a theoretical understanding of polarization and polarizability using functionals.

Let us denote the external electric field generated by free charges (which are all outside of the dielectric medium) as $\textbf{E}_0$ . Here we treat this field and the polarization field on equal footing. The electrostatic potential energy is denoted as $U[\textbf{E}_0, \textbf{P}] = U_{E0} + U_P [\textbf{E}_0, \textbf{P}]$. Here, $U_{E0} = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int \textbf{E}_0 \cdot \textbf{E}_0 d^3r$, which is the normal field energy when there are no dielectrics and $U_P[\textbf{E}_0, \textbf{P}]$ is the energy due to the microscopic dipoles. This is the sum of self terms and interaction terms. The self term contains two terms: $U_{1-dipole}[\textbf{P}]$, which is the energy needed to create the individual dipoles and $U_{dipole-dipole}[\textbf{P}]$, which is sum of the energies of each dipole due to the other dipoles' fields. Consider the term $U_{1 - dipole}[\textbf{P}] = \int d^3r \eta u_d$ , where $\eta$ is the number of the microscopic dipoles per unit volume and $u_d$ is the inertial energy of the dipole. Note that the polarization vector is given by $\textbf{P} = \eta \textbf{p}$. Now, we guess $u_d = \frac{\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{p}}{2 \epsilon_0 \alpha}$ where $\textbf{p}$ is the dipole moment. Now, we want $\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{p}} \bigg( \frac{\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{p}}{2 \epsilon_0 \alpha} - \textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{E}\bigg) = 0$.  This gives us $\textbf{p} = \epsilon_0 \alpha \textbf{E}$, so our guess is correct. Hence we see that $U_{1 - dipole} = \frac{1}{2\epsilon_0 \alpha} \int \bigg( d^3r \frac{\textbf{P}\cdot \textbf{P}}{\eta \alpha}\bigg)$ .

Now we consider $U_{dipole-dipole}$ . This is given by $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j}U_{i,j} $ , or $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i}\textbf{p}_i \cdot \textbf{E}_i$ . In the continuous limit this becomes $\frac{1}{2} \int d^3r \textbf{P} \cdot \textbf{E}_{local}^{self}$. Here, $\textbf{E}_i$ is the field of all the dipoles except that of dipole $i$ . Thus $\textbf{E}_{local}^{self}$ has similar meaning. How do we guess a formula for this field? One thing that is obvious is the notion that this field must depend on the geometry of the polarization and on the superposition principle. To find this, consider a circular void in a uniformly polarized infinite slab. This void represents the space occupied by a microscopic dipole. By superposition we see that the field in the void (i.e. $\textbf{E}_{local}^{self}$) is: $\textbf{E}_{local}^{self} = \textbf{E}_{uniform\_slab\_with\_no\_void} - \textbf{E}_{plug}$, where plug refers to the object obtained from filling up the void and deleting everything that was outside of the void. The geometry dependence is seen by the following two examples

Here is what I mean my longitudinal polarization:

[image]

If we assume that there are no free charges inside the dielectric medium then the \textbf{D} field is 0 and so $\textbf{E}_{uniform\_slab\_with\_no\_void} = - \frac{\textbf{P}}{\epsilon_0}$ . Now, $\textbf{E}_{plug} = -\frac{\textbf{P}}{3 \epsilon_0}$ which was derived previously. Hence $\textbf{E}_{local}^{self} = -\frac{2}{3 \epsilon_0} \textbf{P}$  for longitudinal polarization. For transverse polarization, the dipole moments alternate in direction (up, down, up, down, ... loosely speaking). Intuitively, we see that the system as a whole creates no electric field, i.e $\textbf{E}_{uniform\_slab\_with\_no\_void} = 0$ . $\textbf{E}_{plug} = -\frac{\textbf{P}}{3 \epsilon_0}$ . Hence

$\textbf{E}_{local}^{self} = \textbf{E}_{uniform\_slab\_with\_no\_void} - \textbf{E}_{plug} = \frac{1}{3\epsilon_0}\textbf{P}$ for transversely polarized media. Thus we conclude:

\begin{align}
\textbf{E}_{local}^{self} = \lambda \frac{\textbf{P}}{\epsilon_0} \text{where} \lambda = 1/3 \text{for transverse polarization and $\lambda = -2/3$ for longitudinal polarization.}  
\end{align}

The interaction term refers to the interaction of the dipoles with the external field. This is simply $U_{PE} = - \int \textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{E}_0 d^3 r$. Hence the energy functional evaluates to:

\begin{align}
U[\textbf{E}_0, \textbf{P}] = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int \textbf{E}_0 \cdot \textbf{E}_0 - \int \textbf{P}\cdot \textbf{E}_0 d^3 r + \frac{1}{2\epsilon_0}\bigg( \frac{1}{n\alpha} - \lambda\bigg) \int d^3 r \textbf{P} \cdot \textbf{P} \\
\end{align}

Now we minimize with respect to $\textbf{P}$ by finding the variation of $U$ (denoted as $\delta U[\textbf{E}_0, \textbf{P}]$ ) while we keep $\delta \textbf{E}_0 = 0$ . This works the same way as the product rule for derivatives. We do this minimization procedure since nature creates systems that are at the lowest possible potential energies. We do not minimize the external field because this is an external parameter we can fix (hence $\delta \textbf{E}_0 = 0$).  Doing so gives us a formula for the polarization:

\begin{align}
\textbf{P} = \frac{\epsilon_0 \textbf{E}_0}{(1/\eta\alpha) - \lambda}\\
\end{align}

Is this the correct formula? Recall that we know $\textbf{p} = \alpha \epsilon_0 \textbf{E}_{local} = \alpha \epsilon_0 ( E_{local}^{self} + \textbf{E}_0)$. Hence we see that $\textbf{p} = \alpha (\lambda \textbf{P} + \epsilon_0 \textbf{E}_0 )$ . Here the value determined for $\textbf{E}_{local}^{self}$ is a true statement that follows from the superposition principle; thus it is not a hypothesized value. Also recall that $\textbf{P} = \eta \textbf{p}$  and so $\textbf{P} = \eta \alpha ( \lambda \textbf{P} + \epsilon_0 \textbf{E}_0)$. From this, we see that $\textbf{P} = \frac{\epsilon_0 \textbf{E}}{\frac{1}{\eta \alpha} - \lambda}$ . Hence our functional $U[\textbf{E}_0, \textbf{P}]$ produced the correct formula for the polarization vector.

Now to the experimental scheme. We can measure the external electric field $\textbf{E}_0$ and polarization field **P**. Lambda will be determined by the longitudinal or transverse nature of the polarization. Then, by using the formula $\textbf{P} = \frac{\epsilon_0 \textbf{E}}{\frac{1}{\eta \alpha} - \lambda}$we can solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: I've been staring  at your answer for a week now and the math is just beyond me.  Could you please put the basic concept into plain English for a layman.  Just a few sentences is fine. It's important to me.

Comment: @foolishmuse The last two paragraphs, which start with "Is this the correct formula?," give a simpler explanation. Basically, the formula $\vec{p} = \alpha \epsilon_0 \vec{E}_{local}$ is a standard equation given in most textbooks, and we can use that to find the polarization field in terms of the external field. However, one might ask the origin of this standard formula. To answer that I gave the answer in terms of functionals.

Comment: Thanks.  Once you mentioned that the key is p, I found this video to help me understand.   https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-chemistry-beta/x2eef969c74e0d802:molecular-and-ionic-compound-structure-and-properties/x2eef969c74e0d802:vsepr/v/dipole-moment